# How to check onchildclick in blackberry listfield?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

This is my custom listfield.

```
public class Custom_ListField extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback {
private Vector rows;
private LabelField titletext, datetext, categorytext;
private Bitmap bg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("list_bar.png");

public Custom_ListField(String title[], String date[], String category[]) {
    super(0, ListField.MULTI_SELECT);
    setRowHeight(80);
    setCallback(this);
    Background background = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bg);
    setBackground(background);

    rows = new Vector();

    for (int x = 0; x < title.length; x++) {
        TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager();

        titletext = new LabelField(title[x], DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS
                | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.LEFT);
        titletext.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 20));

        row.add(titletext);

        datetext = new LabelField(date[x], DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS
                | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.LEFT);
        datetext.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));
        row.add(datetext);

        categorytext = new LabelField(category[x], DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS
                | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        //categorytext.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 100);
        categorytext.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));
        row.add(categorytext);
        rows.addElement(row);
    }
    setSize(rows.size());
}

public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y,
        int width) {
    Custom_ListField list = (Custom_ListField) listField;
    TableRowManager rowManager = (TableRowManager) list.rows
            .elementAt(index);
    rowManager.drawRow(g, 0, y, width, list.getRowHeight());
}

private class TableRowManager extends Manager {
    public TableRowManager() {
        super(0);
    }

    public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        layout(width, height);

        setPosition(x, y);
        g.pushRegion(getExtent());
        subpaint(g);
        g.popContext();
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        int fontHeight = Font.getDefault().getHeight();
        int preferredWidth = getPreferredWidth();

        Field field = getField(0);
        layoutChild(field, preferredWidth - 16, fontHeight + 1);
        setPositionChild(field, 5, 5);

        field = getField(1);
        layoutChild(field, 150, fontHeight);
        setPositionChild(field, 5, fontHeight + 5);

        field = getField(2);
        layoutChild(field, 150, fontHeight);
        setPositionChild(field, preferredWidth - 155, fontHeight + 5);

        setExtent(preferredWidth, getPreferredHeight());
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Graphics.getScreenWidth();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return getRowHeight();
    }
}

public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
    return null;
}

public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
    return 0;
}

public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Where to set if clicked then `push screen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you should override `navigationClick(int status, int time)`. Then inside that  get the selected item index by listField.getSelectedIndex() and do what ever you need with it.